# Managing TTL with redis sorted set members

Tags: redis

I'm doing a setup for autocomplete and am looking into using redis sorted sets.  There's quite a bit of documentation on this, but the gist is adding prefixes, for example `abc` would `ZADD mySet` - `0 a`, `0 ab`, `0 abc`, `0 abc*`.

Then as queries come in use `ZRANK` on the query then based on that, use `ZRANGE` to get matching results.

In any case, I want to implement a TTL on not the set, but the specific members of the set.  I know this is not possible out of the box in redis, so I'm looking at implementing an alternative solution.  One option is to use a timestamp as the rank, but this won't work in autocomplete as the rank matters, they need to have the same score to sort lexicographically.

The solution I'm thinking is to effectively replicate the sorted set, into an unsorted set.  This would store values such as `<prefix>:timestamp`.  Then on a schedule can get the members here, check times, delete from sorted set if expired.  Obviously this increases the memory usage, but that's suitable.

My question is are there any better ways to do this? In terms of scale and or simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: OT: look into [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) and [Lexicographical Indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes) for the bigger use case that you're describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Itamar Haber's answer is good, but it needs an extra Sorted Set. In order to decrease the memory usage, you can encode the expiration time into the member. Take the [lexicographical indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes) solution for an example:

**Index**

Suppose you want to index *abc*, and expire it at `1549161254` (unix timestamp). You can encode the term and timestamp as the member name, separated by `\xFE`, i.e. `abc\xFE1549161254`.

```
ZADD set 0 "abc\xFE1549161254"
```

**Query**

When user typing *ab*, you can make a query:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX set "[ab" "[ab\xFF"
```

This will return *abc\xFE1549161254*, then you can split the string with `\xFE`. The first part is the matching member, and the second part is the expiration time. If it's expired, delete it from the sorted set, otherwise, return it to user.

With this solution, you don't need an extra set to save the TTL, and it should be more memory efficient.

Comment: That's a great idea.  Did you choose '\xFE' for a specific reason as a delimiter or just to be unique? Thank you!

Comment: @dzm In fact, it's just a delimiter, and can be any character other than numbers (i.e. `0 - 9`), and `\xFF`. However, if the delimiter might appears in your terms, you need to split the string from the end, NOT from the begin. For example, if the delimiter is `:`, you should split `abc:def:1549161254` into `abc:def` and `1549161254`.

Comment: Nice one @for_stack :)

Comment: @for_stack One issue I'm finding with this method is that instead of updating an existing term, it will add the same term to the set, due to having different expiry times, which in this case, maybe most cases, you would want to update the expiry to the already existing term.  I suppose instead of just adding, could check for it first, using `ZRANGEBYLEX` and remove and re-add.  Not sure how that overhead weights vs. using an additional set.

Comment: @dzm Yes, that's a trade-off between time (complexity) and memory. Which one is better? It totally depends on your scenario. If the memory is NOT a problem, the 2-sorted-set solution might be better. Sorry for the late reply...

Comment: Thanks @for_stack this is working well now, it's a good solution for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Use another Sorted Set to keep track of TTL-like timestamps as scores, query it periodically, or on every call, to find and remove "expired" prefixes.

Comment: Thank you, so using a Sorted Set for this, by setting the timestamps to be an expired-on time, I could use `ZRANGEBYSCORE mySet -inf <CURRENT_TIMESTAMP>` to effectively get all keys that need to be removed?

Comment: Exactly, and follow that by an additional ZREMRANGEBYSCORE on mySet to clean them from it, and then go to the first set and remove the results returned from the query from it.